# How to use a variable received from i2c in my void loop

Tags: arduino, i2c

I decided to use i2c to connect two arduinos to split the load between them. The master will receive data from an esp8266 wi-fi module and transmit it to the slave that will use that data as a reference point for a PİD controller. But i cannot use the received data. İt's stuck in the void receiveEvent(howMany) function. Any idea on how the call an int received from there into the main void loop? I'm sure it's a very noob questions, but I've searched for days and couldn't find an answer or example that uses the void loop. Thanks

Comment: since i2c has no "types", i think you need to collect the bytes and re-assemble it yourself. if it's always <255, just use a `byte` instead of an `int`... watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AP1Da-iL3dg

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) I've no problem receiving data. It's just that I cannot use it. If i use Serial.print inside the receiveEvent function i can read it but i cannot find how to get my variable out of there and into my void loop. The nature of a PID controller requires me to loop it until error is minimized. The exaple you mentioned doesn't use the void loop

Comment: ahh, just assign the value to a global variable that can be reached from anywhere.

Comment: Tried that and still no luck.

Comment: void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
byte x = Wire.read();    // read one character from the I2C
 
}

Comment: in that case, `x` is local to `receiveEvent`. you need to declare `x` "up top", outside of any functions. you know, just after the #includes...

Comment: it gets to the slave, i'm sure. But it's stuck there in that function. it's not a normal function i can call, and return x gives an error. cant figure out how to get it out. Do you need the code?

Comment: if it's in an interrupt, you need to declare the global as `volatile`. i'll look at your code to see if something pops out, if you can put it on codepen or pagebin or whatever and post a link. the main idea is like `int x=1; void test(){ x = x + 1; } void loop(){ Serial.println(x); test(); }`

Comment: yeah declared it there also. but when i do that x stays as 0

Comment: okay will try that and send the code.

Comment: hmm. weird. i'd have to see the code ;)...  last guess: `void receiveEvent(int howMany) { byte x = Wire.read();} ` should be more like `void receiveEvent(int howMany) { x = Wire.read();} `

Comment: https://codepen.io/FitzValiant/pen/OWyJZx

Comment: was too lazy to figure out how codepen worked. but i put the master in css and slave in js. It works now and i did as you said. Thanks a million the code just takes a desired input from an arduino mega and sends it to a nano, which calculates pid and moves a motor. The esp8266 wifi shield i will add to the mega tomorrow and update desired position from there. I might have forgotten to remove all the crude language from my comments so please forgive me for that. And once again, thanks a lot

Comment: what does `void receiveEvent(int howMany) {  x = Wire.read(); Serial.println("getting " + String(int)+"b, seeing: " +String(x)); }` log? the bigger file looks ok at a glance...